# Changing position of data in columns depending on actual data

Tags: t-sql

Suppose I have a table like below

```
ID  Marks1  Marks2  Marks3
-------------------------
1   10      0       4
2   0      40       90
```

Now, I need to select from this table in a way that will give precedence to positive values first. So if the marks are 0 then it will be shifted to right. The SELECT should give following output

```
ID  Marks1  Marks2  Marks3
-------------------------
1   10      4       0
2   40      90      0
```

Can you please guide me for the approach? It will be great if it can be done in a select statement itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you will need to check for each subsequent row that the previous column isn't 0. Have selected the values out as null as it makes the code slightly easier to read as i can use coalesce

```
Select
Coalesce(Marks1, Marks2, Marks3,0) as Marks1,
Case when marks1 is not null 
     then Coalesce(Marks2, Marks3, 0) else 0 
end as Marks2,
case when marks1 is not null 
     and marks2 is not null 
     then Coalesce(Marks3,0) 
end as Marks3

from
(
Select
Case when Marks1 =0 then null else Marks1 end as Marks1,
Case when Marks2 =0 then null else Marks2 end as Marks2,
Case when Marks3 =0 then null else Marks3 end as Marks3
  From mytbl
)
```

Comment: gr8.. Thanks for the approach! Seems very logical.. Only the problem seems to be when Mark1 is null then we need ELSE as well right? This may make it bit complex but seems that is the only alternative.

Comment: Marks 1 should end up as 0 as in the outer select has coalesce (marks1,2,3,0). Coalesce will work down the tree till one of them is non null.